# gorm use the find rerurn empty

Tags: go, go-gorm

I use the find method to find some records,but when I send the wrong condition.it should return the
ErrRecordNotFound,but it return a empty struct

```
var projectSetBudget domain.ProjectSetBudget
filter := &domain.ProjectSetBudget{}
filter.TenantID = tenantID
filter.ID = ProjectSetBudgetID
res := r.db.Where(filter).Find(&projectSetBudget)
```

i just print the info

```
zap.S().Info(errors.Is(res.Error, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound))
```

it print false

and return  the empty struct

```
{
    "ID": 0,
    "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "DeletedAt": null,
    "title": "",
}
```

Comment: just print error, there can be another error. If there is an error, your struct is empty.

Comment: maybe the gorm will return a empty struct if it find no record. I add the "omitempty" tag to the field can help. I find the answer in [named hyperlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53671115/gorm-return-empty-object-instead-default-object-when-value-is-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

*GORM provides **First, Take, Last methods** to retrieve a single object from the database, it adds LIMIT 1 condition when querying the database, and it will return the error ErrRecordNotFound if no record is found.*
https://gorm.io/docs/query.html

only **First, Take, Last methods** but find
if you use **First, Take, Last** there will be ErrRecordNotFound

**First, Take, Last** have folow code, but find have not, find will find not only one, so you can know it found or not by count:

```
tx.Statement.RaiseErrorOnNotFound = true
```